# Count for bit columns in select statement with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, group-by

Struggling a little bit here.

I have 2 columns (selected and completed) of which I need to get the counts respectively.

```
Module                  Topic               Selected  Completed

Applying for finance    Application process     0   NULL
Applying for finance    Application outcome     1   NULL
Applying for finance    Registration process    1   NULL
Applying for finance    Insurance options       1   NULL
Applying for finance    Repayment options       1   NULL
Applying for finance    Application process     0   NULL
Applying for finance    Application outcome     1   1
Applying for finance    Registration process    1   1
Applying for finance    Insurance options       1   1
Applying for finance    Repayment options       1   1
```

How could I construct the select query to return as follow

```
 Module                  Topic               Selected  Completed

Applying for finance    Application process     0   0
Applying for finance    Application outcome     2   1
Applying for finance    Registration process    2   1
Applying for finance    Insurance options       2   1
Applying for finance    Repayment options       2   1
```

My approach has been something like this, but doesn't quite return the expected outcome.

```
    select
m.Module,
t.Topic,
count (tu.Selected) as Selected,
count (tu.Completed) as Completed
from TopicUser tu
inner join Users u on u.Id = tu.UserId
inner join Topics t on tu.TopicId = t.TopicId
inner join Module m on m.ModuleId = t.ModuleId

group by m.Module, t.Topic, Completed 

order by Module asc
```

Ideally the Topic columns should not repeat

Both the Selected and Completed columns are bit

Kind regards

Comment: Simple rule: GROUP BY all selected columns that are not arguments to aggregate functions:

Comment: I believe that you want `SUM(tu.Selected)` instead of `count (tu.Selected)`

Comment: Correct, thanks. I used SUM instead and that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 select
m.Module,
t.Topic,
count (tu.Selected) as Selected,
count (tu.Completed) as Completed
from TopicUser tu
inner join Users u on u.Id = tu.UserId
inner join Topics t on tu.TopicId = t.TopicId
inner join Module m on m.ModuleId = t.ModuleId

group by m.Module, t.Topic

order by Module asc
```

You have `left` the `Completed` column in the group by. We do not want to do this as the results are going to be grouped by it and more rows are going to returned.